# Meteor - Execute code on every page load

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I want to execute a function when any page loads.

Things like `Meteor.startup()` and `Template.myTemplate.onRendered()` are not what I want because they are triggered only once, when the app is loaded.

Basically I need an event that is triggered every time the URL changes, is there one?

Comment: What router are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `onRun` or `onBeforeAction` to run arbitrary code on every route change.

```
Router.onRun(function(){
  console.log('onRun', this.current().route.getName());
  this.next();
});

Router.onBeforeAction(function(){
  console.log('onBeforeAction', this.current().route.getName());
  this.next();
});
```

Use this placeholder code to detect when this code will actually run.

`onRun` will run only once on every route change. (good for analytics related stuff)
`onBeforeAction` will reactively rerun when the current route data context is modified.